# How do you know that your database queries are taking time and how will you solve it?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

Recently at an interview I was asked this question : How do you know that your database queries are taking time and how will you solve it ?

I could not think of any particular answer for this.
Though I cleared the interview and got the offer letter but still wondering what will be answer to this question.

Comment: Check DMVs, check execution plans, change code, add indexing some of the options depending on problem.

Comment: @RogerClerkwell Is DMV a thing outside of MS SQL Server?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: In SQL Server, Sorry not sure of equivalent to DMV in other dbs like Oracle etc.

Comment: Can using `EXPLAIN` keyword be an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an interceptor which does the logging before and after querying your database. You can check from the logs then how much time is being taken by the query. If you see database is slow, you can introduce indexing on columns which are being used frequently in where clause.